# Android: Strip all html except for img tags

Tags: android

In Java, I saw one can easily specify whitelist tags and strip rest of the html tags:

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
whitelist.addTags(new String[] { "p", "br", "ul" });

String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, whitelist);
return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(safe);
```

PHP also has `strip_tags($html, $whitelist)` function to do the same.

I saw in Android, you can do this:

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml(instruction).toString()
```

But that will strip whole html including img tags.

Alternatively, `Jsoup` library can be used but don't we have simpler solution instead of using this `300kb` library for this simple requirement ?

In Android, how can I strip all html except for `<img>` tags in given text ?

Comment: Not sure why downvote, this is very legitimate question asking about similar solutions for android. I need to allow only `<img>` tags in `TextView`

Comment: fromHtml() will load the html and in some cases render the HTML tags in the TextView NOT strip them - see http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: If you use ProGuard, all unused code, including unused Jsoup classes and methods, will be removed from your build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it does the job:

- Substitute all img tags for some special string so the stripping function can't see them
- Strip out all HTML
- Substitute the special string for the img tags to get them back.

  ```
  String stripHTMLtagsExceptIMG(String htmlString)
  {
      String subbed = htmlString.replaceAll("< *[iI][mM][gG]", "_iimmgg");
      String stripped = android.text.Html.fromHtml(subbed).toString();
      String unsubbed = stripped.replaceAll("_iimmgg", "<img");

      return unsubbed;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks I think this will do the job until there is better solution. Thanks